# How to format my pendrive with f2fs filsystem using gparted?

Tags: usb-drive, gparted, f2fs

I have a Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive 2GB pendrive which I would like to format using [f2fs partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F2FS). I tried using gparted 0.18 to format it however, f2fs seems to be disabled.

Is it possible to format my pendrive using f2fs? If yes, how do I do it using gparted

**P.S.:** If it is not possible using gparted 0.18, alternatives are most welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install `f2fs-tools`:

```
sudo apt-get install f2fs-tools
```

This will install `/sbin/mkfs.f2fs` and that should activate the `f2fs` option for `gparted`:

[image]